# how could this operation on array be implemented?

Tags: objective-c, c

I could try to implement it:

```
if( result[col]>max(result)-4000 ){
  printf("%d",col);
}
```

In this code; if exists col,col+1 or col+2, i will take the biggest of them,only one.
How could it be implemented?

Thanks..

Comment: [What's this for](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)? Is the [sample complete](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

In Cocoa, you use [`-objectAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) with NSArrays rather than square brackets to index an array. `max` could be implemented as a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) on NSArray, using [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1). Depending on what else you are doing, you might use fast enumeration rather than `-objectAtIndex:`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, this is equivalent to printing the maximum, as the maxmimum will always be larger than itself - 4000, and it's the biggest of 'them'. Why do you want to print this number? I think there's an error in your logic somewhere.